# AzureCli@2 Task, multiline arguments?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a pipeline task as such

I want to pass in a multiline string to arguments, but it is not working.
I see in the docs, both InlineScript and Arguments are both type 'string'... and I can use this multiline syntax on InlineScript?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/azure-cli-v2?view=azure-pipelines

I don't want to fit all my arguments on 1 line because it expands to a total of 250 characters and is hard for readability.

```
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: 'do thing'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: $(myServiceConnection)
    scriptType: 'pscore'
    scriptLocation: 'scriptPath'
    scriptPath: 'myscript.ps1'
    arguments: |
       -arg1switch
       -arg2 aString
       -arg3 aString
       ...
       -argN aString
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe there can be used something similar to PowerShell@2 syntax?

```
 arguments: > # Use this to avoid newline characters in multiline string
  -input1 "Hello"
  -input2 "World"
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/powershell-v2?view=azure-pipelines#call-powershell-script-with-multiple-arguments